# How to fix this uncaught error in electron for mainrenderer?

Tags: javascript, electron

Folks I hope you are pretty well. I got an error while rendering other html and js from render and am a newbie 
[image]

Please have a look at my main.js and one.js inside mainrenderer folder 
here's my git link:

https://github.com/neetesshhr/jstut-.git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an invalid syntax while passing the options to the `BrowserWindow` constructor [here](https://github.com/neetesshhr/jstut-/blob/master/MainRenderer/one.js#L9).
You should wrap `webReferences` in the object literal (note the additional curly braces):

```
let winThree = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true
    }
});
```